# Multiple datatypes in column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I have had a look, and from what I can tell, this is a case of you can't have your cake and eat it too, but I thought I'd ask in-case any one knows of a workaround I could use.

I'm building up a DataGridView control programmatically, with basically two columns, Field Name and Value, the source data is coming from our CRM system, which is stored in a complex manner, so this was deemed the best format to retrieve.

The problem I am having is that it won't render HTML tags when they are drawn from the database, the same with email addresses, I manually turn them into hrefs so they can simply be clicked on the page to open a new email.

With the example below, whats stored in the DB is the http:// address, I have made it into a html tag, otherwise it just shows the URL as plain text.

```
result.value = "<a href= """ & result.value & ">" & result.value & "</a>"
```

[Display of data - added href tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOhc.jpg)

From items I've read, adding the htmlEncode to the value would work, but it doesn't.

```
result.value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result.value)
```

[Display of data - added htmlencode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu7W7.jpg)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this column display both Strings, and Hyperlinks?

The full method I'm using is here:

```
Private Sub getData()
    'DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0
    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue Is "" Then
        ' assume firstrun

    Else
        'assume not firstrun
        firstrun = False
        thisClientID = dbconn.getClientID(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
        Dim results As List(Of DataDump) = dbconn.GetAllData(thisClientID)

        Label1.Text = "(CRM ID: " & thisClientID & ")"

        alldc = New DataColumn()
        'dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("system.string")
        'alldc.ColumnName = "Tab"
        'alldc.ReadOnly = "True"
        'AllDataTable.Columns.Add(alldc)

        alldc = New DataColumn()
        ' dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("system.string")
        alldc.ColumnName = "Field"
        alldc.ReadOnly = "True"


        AllDataTable.Columns.Add(alldc)



        alldc = New DataColumn()
        'alldc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("system.hyperlink")
        alldc.ColumnName = "Value"
        alldc.ReadOnly = "True"
        AllDataTable.Columns.Add(alldc)

        CompanyDetailsDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        ConnectionDetailsDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        EnvironmentalConfigurationDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        ModulesInstalledDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        OnlineConfigurationDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        PensionDetailsDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        PeopleDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        SupportDetailsDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        SystemConfigurationDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone
        UATSystemDataTable = AllDataTable.Clone

        ' Instantiate the DataSet variable.
        Dim AllDetailsDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim CompanyDetailsDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim ConnectionDetailsDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim EnvironmentalConfigurationDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim ModulesInstalledDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim OnlineConfigurationDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim PensionDetailsDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim PeopleDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim SupportDetailsDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim SystemConfigurationDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim UATSystemDataset As New DataSet()

        ' Add the new DataTable to the DataSet.
        AllDetailsDataSet.Tables.Add(AllDataTable)
        CompanyDetailsDataset.Tables.Add(CompanyDetailsDataTable)
        ConnectionDetailsDataset.Tables.Add(ConnectionDetailsDataTable)
        EnvironmentalConfigurationDataset.Tables.Add(EnvironmentalConfigurationDataTable)
        ModulesInstalledDataset.Tables.Add(ModulesInstalledDataTable)
        OnlineConfigurationDataset.Tables.Add(OnlineConfigurationDataTable)
        PensionDetailsDataset.Tables.Add(PensionDetailsDataTable)
        PeopleDataset.Tables.Add(PeopleDataTable)
        SupportDetailsDataset.Tables.Add(SupportDetailsDataTable)
        SystemConfigurationDataset.Tables.Add(SystemConfigurationDataTable)
        UATSystemDataset.Tables.Add(UATSystemDataTable)

        For Each result As DataDump In results
            alldr = AllDataTable.NewRow()
            Select Case True
                Case result.value.StartsWith("http")
                    'Hyperlinks

                    result.value = "<a href= """ & result.value & ">" & result.value & "</a>"
                    'result.value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result.value)
                ' ****** need to make hyperlinks work
                Case result.value.Contains("\")
                    'Connection Strings
                    Do While result.value.Contains("\\")
                        result.value = Replace(result.value, "\\", "\")
                    Loop
                Case result.value.Contains("@") And result.value.Contains(".")
                    'Email Addresses - set as hyper link
                    result.value = "<a href= ""mailto:" & result.value & ">" & result.value & "</a>"
                Case Else
            End Select

            'alldr("Tab") = result.tabname
            alldr("Field") = result.fieldname
            alldr("Value") = result.value
            Select Case result.tabname
                Case "Company Details"
                    CompanyDetailsDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Connection Details"
                    ConnectionDetailsDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Environmental Configuration"
                    EnvironmentalConfigurationDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Modules Installed (Live)"
                    ModulesInstalledDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Online Configuration"
                    OnlineConfigurationDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Pension Details"
                    PensionDetailsDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "People"
                    PeopleDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "Support Details"
                    SupportDetailsDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "System Configuration"
                    SystemConfigurationDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case "UAT System"
                    UATSystemDataTable.Rows.Add(result.fieldname, result.value)

                Case Else

            End Select
            'AllDataTable.Rows.Add(result.tabname, result.fieldname, result.value)
        Next
        CompDetailsGV.DataSource = CompanyDetailsDataset
        ConnDetailsGV.DataSource = ConnectionDetailsDataset
        EnvironmentalDetailsGV.DataSource = EnvironmentalConfigurationDataset
        ModulesDetailsGV.DataSource = ModulesInstalledDataset
        OnlineDetailsGV.DataSource = OnlineConfigurationDataset
        PensionDetailsGV.DataSource = PensionDetailsDataset
        peopleDetailsGV.DataSource = PeopleDataset
        SupportDetailsGV.DataSource = SupportDetailsDataset
        SystemDetailsGV.DataSource = SystemConfigurationDataset
        UATDetailsGV.DataSource = UATSystemDataset


        CompDetailsGV.DataBind()
        ConnDetailsGV.DataBind()
        EnvironmentalDetailsGV.DataBind()
        ModulesDetailsGV.DataBind()
        OnlineDetailsGV.DataBind()
        PensionDetailsGV.DataBind()
        peopleDetailsGV.DataBind()
        SupportDetailsGV.DataBind()
        SystemDetailsGV.DataBind()
        UATDetailsGV.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this question related to web forms or windows forms? You are using the windows forms [tag:datagridview] tag, but are also using the [tag:asp.net] tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the column to be DataGridViewLinkColumn so your

```
alldc = New DataColumn()
```

must be replaced to

```
alldc = New DataGridViewLinkColumn()
```

and set the column to true

```
alldc.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
```

Did you already try this?

Comment: that class is for Windows Forms and not Web Content.

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=datagridviewlinkcolumn+asp+net